# Codeigniter 3 Unable to access an error message

Tags: php, forms, validation, codeigniter

I have proble with set_rules function in Codeigniter 3

i check user email:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean|valid_email');
```

and when I post get this error:

**Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Email.**

Comment: Do you have change the default language ? Is your input name "email" ?

Comment: this is my input name "email" and no, I don't change default language

Comment: Check if the file system/language/english/form_validation_lang.php exists

Comment: yes exist but if i remove this xss_clean works fine

Comment: Did you migrate your app from CI2 ?

Answer (score 57):

From the codeigniter github :

> A largely unknown rule about XSS cleaning is that it should only be
>   applied to output, as opposed to input data.
>
> We've made that mistake ourselves with our automatic and global XSS
>   cleaning feature (see previous step about XSS above), so now in an
>   effort to discourage that practice, **we're also removing 'xss_clean'
>   from the officially supported list of form validation rules**.
>
> Because the Form Validation library generally validates input data, the
>   'xss_clean' rule simply doesn't belong in it.
>
> **If you really, really need to apply that rule, you should now also
>   load the Security Helper**, which contains xss_clean() as a regular function and therefore can be also used as a validation rule.

Link : https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/user_guide_src/source/installation/upgrade_300.rst#step-13-check-for-usage-of-the-xss_clean-form-validation-rule

And if, despite everything, you really need it, go to application/config/autoload.php :

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('security');
```

Or, before your form validation

```
$this->load->helper('security');
```

Comment: yep, with $autoload['helper'] = array('security'); works fine, thx:)

Comment: Use the autoload.php to load the security helper. It is better to use this helper to make a secure application.

Answer (score 12):

### xss_clean is no longer part of form validation.

The alternative is not to use it, as **xss_clean** is doing sanitization and not validation.
 **xss_clean** is part of security helper. If you need to do it, after validation you do.

> ```
>  $this->load->helper('security'); `
>  $value = $this->input->post('email',TRUE); //where TRUE enables the xss filtering
> ```

Also, you can enable global xss filtering in the config.php file

> `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;`

Answer (score 6):

Others have alluded to it, but no one has said succinctly, the way to fix this error is to remove `xxs_clean` from your validation rule. I just came across this issue myself, and thanks to the hints provided here, was able to fix the issue.

This:

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean|valid_email');
```

Becomes this:

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
```

Answer (score 6):

Please load `security` Helper on autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('security');
```

No need to do anything more.

Answer (score 0):

Global overriding the rule would be expanding it with custom message next way:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean|valid_email',
        array('xss_clean' => 'Error Message: your xss is not clean.')
);
```

Comment: There's a little typo in your answer: `$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean|valid_email',
        array('xss_clean' => 'Error Message: your xss is not clean.')
);`

Comment: @SebastianPalma Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use.

```
$this->load->helper('security');
```

Also you can use the below code in config/autoload.php ,But I prefer use the above one. Since, it keeps the Codeigniter lite weight.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('security');
```