# Codeigniter 3 + Tank auth throws error: Unknown column 'data' in 'field list'

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication, tankauth

Can you help me please with authentication in Codeigniter? I start with CI yesterday so I am little confused.
I found [Tank auth library](https://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/), but it seems it is not compatible with CI3. It throws me an error: "Unknown column 'data' in 'field list'" from libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php 
Session library expects the field name data in ci_session table. My ci_session table comes from Tank auth download and there is user_data field instead. What can I do? Or is there a better authentication library for CI3? I wolud like to find lib with authentication + authorisation.

Comment: Try with Ion Auth by Ben Edmunds, member of CI council.

Comment: Thanks, I found it too and it looks really good. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but it might be useful to someone. To get [Tank Auth](https://github.com/TankAuth/Tank-Auth) working in Codeigniter 3:

In `config.php`, remove the options which are no longer in the new default `config.php`, and add the ones specified in the [upgrade guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html).

Set `sess_driver` to `files`:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
```

And add an absolute path to the `sess_save_path` option:

```
$config['sess_save_path']   = BASEPATH . 'sessions';
```

In the `Auth` controller, remove `$this->load->library('security');` this is because the security library is loaded automatically.

In the same controller, add `$this->load->helper('security');` -- this allows the XSS clean method which is used in Tank Auth's default controller. You might as well also remove `xss_clean` from the validation rules in the `Auth` controller - these are now obsolete. See this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568871/codeigniter-3-unable-to-access-an-error-message) Stack Overflow question.

All this is of course assuming that the rest of the instructions in the [upgrade guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html) have been followed.